# How do I accept a function as an input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm trying to write a program that accepts and evaluates a simple function as such:

```
A=[]
v = input("Enter Function of x: "
o = input("Enter length of range: ")

for x in range (1,o+1):
    f = (v)
    A.append(f)
```

but this just returns the function text (input string) 'o' times in a list. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Thanks to @tdelaney for the answer: use f=eval(v)

Comment: What are you entering as `v` input ?

Comment: Something simple, for instance I'd expect something like x**2

Comment: Along with the input, what do you expect `A` to look like? (In general, your answer will consist of parsing the input and producing an appropriate value. How you do that depends on what exactly `v` looks like and what you actually want to do with the parsed result.)

Comment: In the future, just use regular code formatting for posting code, snippets are only for html, css, and javascript.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @user3501859 Your `f` is not a function, it is a string.

Comment: I'm using python 3.6

Comment: @Goyo How can I convert a string into a function then?

Comment: @user3501859 According to your comments to Prune's answer you do not need that.

Answer (score 2):

`v` is merely a character string.  Throwing parentheses around it makes it a tuple of one element -- the same string.  You haven't done anything to turn it into a function -- which is not trivial in any programming language, as you're trying to inject new code into a program that has already been parsed.

Python supplies the [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) function for doing this.  Beware, however, as `eval` is quite powerful and dangerous.

```
my_func = "x*x + 2*x - 3"
limit = 5
y_vals = []

for x in range (1,limit+1):
    y_vals.append(eval(my_func))

print(y_vals)
```

Output:

```
[0, 5, 12, 21, 32]
```

Comment: I don't understand, if I enter x^2 directly into f = (x^2) it gives me the expected result. So I figured if I have the user input that string, shouldn't the code interpret that as though I had entered it directly into f?

Comment: Not on my Python; `x2` is an undefined variable.  `x*2` would be a legal expression.

Comment: I have no idea what any of that means hahah. Also I'm aware of the legal expression for x squared, I just wanted to communicate it here in the comments since x * * 2 returns x2 here

Comment: No, the interpreter should *not* evaluate that string as if it were inserted into the code stream.  I certainly wouldn't want it to treat my true string data that way!

Comment: Hopefully the reason for that will make sense to me eventually. In the mean time, I need a way to accept a function to dump into f=() in my loop. How would I do that simply?

Comment: @user3501859 - `f = eval(v)`

Comment: @user3501859: look at my answer: there's code to do that.  I improved your variable names and elided the `f =` step into the `append`